# issue with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query, in which I used `JOIN`s. It says:

> unknown column m.bv ..

Could you please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$query4 =  'SELECT u.*, SUM(c.ts) AS total_sum1, SUM(m.bv) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon GROUP BY user_id) c 
 ON u.user_id=c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS bv FROM matching GROUP BY user_id) r 
ON u.user_id=m.user_id 
where u.user_id="'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'"
GROUP BY u.user_id';
```

Comment: you do not have table "m" here in your query. PS please do not use caps

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting `SUM(points) AS bv` from the table with the alias `r`, there is no tables with the alias `m`. So that it has to be `r.bv` instead like so:

```
SELECT 
  u.*, 
  SUM(c.ts) AS total_sum1, 
  SUM(r.bv) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      SUM(points) AS ts 
    FROM coupon 
    GROUP BY user_id
) c ON u.user_id=c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      SUM(points) AS bv 
     FROM matching 
     GROUP BY user_id
) r ON u.user_id = m.user_id 
where u.user_id="'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'"
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace m., with r. Look at second Join

Answer (score 0):

You have aliased the derived table with `r` and you reference that table (twice) with `m`. Correct one or the other.

Since you group by `user_id` in the two subqueries and `user_id` is (I assume) the primary key of table `user`, you don't really need the final `GROUP BY`.

I would write it like this, if it was meant for all (many) users:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(c.ts, 0) AS total_sum1, COALESCE(m.bv, 0) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon GROUP BY user_id) c 
   ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS bv FROM matching GROUP BY user_id) m  
   ON u.user_id = m.user_id
```

and like this in your (one user) case:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(c.ts, 0) AS total_sum1, COALESCE(m.bv, 0) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon
      WHERE user_id = "'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'") c 
    ON TRUE 
  LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT SUM(points) AS bv FROM matching
      WHERE user_id = "'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'") m
   ON TRUE 
WHERE u.user_id = "'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'"
```

The last query can also be simplified to:

```
SELECT u.*, 
     COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(points) FROM coupon 
                WHERE user_id = u.user_id)
             , 0) AS total_sum1,
     COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(points) FROM matching 
                WHERE user_id = u.user_id)
             , 0) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.user_id = "'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'"
```